# Uso de chaves para exibir javascript

Tags: javascript

Com o angular e outros frameworks constuma-se exibir valores ou chamar funcões javascript dentro de chaves no meio de codigos html.exemplo:

`<div>{{exibeNome()}}</div>`

Como posso usar isso sem esses frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esses frameworks compilam HTML e inserem o que está dentro de `{{ }}` no HTML. Isso é feito de maneira diferente de framework para framework.

Isso pode ser bem complexo e à partida desecessário re-inventar. Exemplos disso são como referiste o Angular mas também Pug, Ejs, JSX, etc.

Se tiveres um objeto e um pedaço de HTML, a coisa poderia ser feita assim, de forma muito simplista:

```js
var conteudo = {
  nome: 'Maria',
  idade: function() {
    return new Date().getFullYear() - 1978;
  }
}


function parser(html) {
  var regex = /{{(.+?)}}/g;
  return html.replace(/{{(.+?)}}/g, function(match, cmd) {
    return eval('conteudo.' + cmd.trim());
  });
}


var p = document.querySelector('p');
p.innerHTML = parser(p.innerHTML, conteudo);
```

```html
<p>A {{ nome }} tem {{ idade() }} de idade.</p>
```

As ideias dentro desse código são:

- encontrar os comandos a executar sobre o objeto/classe com o *conteudo*
- criar uma função que corra `eval()` dentro do contexto correto, podia ser usando um `.bind()` mas simplifiquei aqui
- substituir os valores no HTML